# how to raise an exception if a variable read from yaml file is not declared in the yaml file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am reading variables from a yaml file:

```
begin
  settings = YAML.load_file 'vm.yaml'

  $var_a   = settings['var_a']
  $var_b   = settings['var_b']
  ....
  $var_z   = settings['var_z']

rescue
  puts "\nInvalid vm.yaml - please create or recreate vm.yaml from vm.yaml.example\n\n"
  exit 1
end

puts $var_a
```

If a variable is not set in the vm.yaml file, the error will not be detected until the variable is first accessed (e.g. at `puts $var_a`).

Preferably, I would like the code in the rescue block to be executed if the variable is not set in the yaml file.

What is the most rubyist way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fetch instead of [] to access the hash data.

So instead of `settings['var_a']` do `settings.fetch('var_a')`

By default, this will raise an error if the key does not exist. But the fetch method also takes an optional block that is executed if the key isn't found.

This can allow you to set up a default return value:
`settings.fetch('var_a') { 'foo' }`

or create a custom failure message:

`settings.fetch('var_a') { fail "Key var_a was not found, please add it to the yaml" }`

Comment: @DaneAnderson - thanks!  How would one fetch a nested element?  E.g. `var_a_a = settings['var_a']['a']`

Comment: Given you are loading data from a yaml file, you're likely working with nested hashes. They can be a little hard to wrap your brain around at first, but at the heart of it it means the response to the method `settings.fetch('var_a')` is a hash, and so you can carry on using either [] or fetch to get values of the hash that was returned, making it `settings.fetch('var_a').fetch('a')`